# All-in-one downloadable HTML file including chart.js from nuxt app

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

My requirement is to provide a small Nuxt app that generate a simple HTML file including some overview sections for services provided to customers of the company I work for. The specific use case here is that the app provides an HTML file that is downloadable and can be opened again in any browser, on or offline with 100% of the functionality.

This works with SSR and Nuxt, however, I'm running into some problems with using chart.js

Current state of the app: Super basic Nuxt app generated via `nuxi`, three Vue components. One of the components implements `chart.js`, all of this results in this:

[image]

However, when I save the resulting file (`mhtml` or `html`), the chart portion doesnt show up. The `Chart` component is essentially just this:

```
 methods: {
      renderChart() {
        const ctx = this.$refs.chartCanvas.getContext('2d');
  
        new Chart(ctx, {
          type: 'pie',
          data: {
            labels: ['green', 'red'],
            datasets: [{
              data: [this.green, this.red],
              backgroundColor: ['green', 'red']
            }]
          },
          options: {
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

which is called in `onMounted`, and rendered like so:

```
<template>
    <div>
      <canvas ref="chartCanvas"></canvas>
    </div>
 </template>
```

I've tried building the app in different ways (static and server targets), but that didn't help.

Is this a problem with lifecycle hooks not being available via SSR? Or a problem with my implementation specifically?

Comment: Please clarify, is your app _creating_ those "downloadable" HTML documents that are supposed to contain everything, or are you _just_ using the "save page as" feature of your browser? Your initial description make it sound as if it was the former, but then _"However, when I save the resulting file (mhtml or html)"_ rather suggests it might be the latter ...?

Comment: The goal is for those to be identical. However, the requirement from the users is that they're able to use the "Save Page as" feature of the browser and have the resulting file be identical to what the application would serve them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easier route may be to export the canvas as datauri then use the buffer string as a src on a download button. This way you are just exporting the graph as a png or similar. By the sounds of it you are wanting to make graphs server side then make them available to download and this is the best/ most obvious way to accomplish this.

Comment: Yup, this works and is very simple to implement, thanks!


Requires sacrificing some of the interactivity that chart.js provides but it's nontheless worth it